# How to used Universal link for application?

Tags: swift, ios-universal-links

I need to used universal link for inter application communication for third party library.
I have uploaded AASA(apple-app-site-association) file to server and it's pass all the validation ([Here](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)). Here is the screenshot

[image]

> Assosiated domain

[image]

I also put the code of deeplink

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL
        {
            print("Incoming url is \(incomingURL)")

        } 


        return true

    }
```

But still i have question which link i need to refer as universal link also I used link at where AASA file uploaded but still it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: The weblink that you want to open both in the website and the app are the universal links. The weblinks that you want to work in such a way must be included in the AASA file.

Comment: @PGDev understood but currently it's only open website not my application any idea about this?

Comment: Have you added it in your AASA file?

Comment: @PGDev I have added AASA File with team id and bundle identifier

Comment: And what about the links that you have added AASA for?

Comment: Refer this article on how to work with Universal Links. https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Comment: @PGDev I already refer that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figure out the problem. I need to use association domain link as Universal link other all the things are right

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add the Associated Domains Entitlement to your app. Include the domains supported by your app using the applinks service prefix. See Add the Associated Domains Entitlement.